# $f(x+1) + f(x-1) = x^2$ ; $f(x+4) + f(x-4) = 2\sin x$ , then $f(x) =$?

Tags: functions

Given $f$ is a complex valued function satisfying $$f(x+1) + f(x-1) = x^2 \\ 
f(x+4) + f(x-4) = 2\sin x$$
what is $f(x)$ ?
Here,  only for the first part MathWolfram alpha is showing $f(x)$ to be of type $c_1(i)^x + c_2(-i)^x + \dfrac{x^2 - 1}{2}$ but how are they introducing "$i$"? I used a generating function but was still unable to get those terms containing $i$ . Please help me with this problem.

Comment: "but how are they introducing "i"?" -- Based on which terms these are, namely attached to constant terms, the $i$ likely arises from Wolfram solving this as one would the linear, homogenous recurrence relation $T(n+1) = -T(n-1)$. This has a characteristic equation of the form $r^{n+1} = - r^{n-1} \implies r^2 = -1$. The roots of this characteristic equation would help determine the general, non-recursive solution for $T$. Were the roots $r_1,r_2$, then we could say

$$T(n) = c_1r_1^n + c_2 r_2^n$$

for constants $c_1,c_2$ that depending on known values of $T$ for particular $n$. [cont]

Comment: Since $r_1,r_2$ are obviously $+i,-i$, that's where those come from. Of course, these usually assume discrete values of your variable, e.g. that $n$ is an integer. But I imagine your case has $x$ as any real number, integer or not. Sadly Wolfram usually can't distinguish and goes with its best guess.

Comment: Could you please explain for the term (x^2 - 1)/2 that follows

Comment: The $(x^2 - 1)/2$ term likely results from the non-homogenous part of the relation, and accounting for that as you solve the relation.

Answer (score 2):

The two conditions can be rewritten as
$$f(x+2)+f(x)=(x+1)^2$$
$$f(x+8)+f(x)=2\sin(x+4)$$

Iterating the first one gives
$$f(x+4)+f(x+2)=(x+3)^2$$
$$f(x+6)+f(x+4)=(x+5)^2$$
$$f(x+8)+f(x+6)=(x+7)^2$$

It follows

\begin{align}
2\sin(x+4) &= f(x+8)+f(x)\\
&= (x+7)^2-f(x+6)+f(x)\\
&= (x+7)^2-(x+5)^2+f(x+4)+f(x)\\
&= (x+7)^2-(x+5)^2+(x+3)^2-f(x+2)+f(x)\\
&= (x+7)^2-(x+5)^2+(x+3)^2-(x+1)^2+f(x)+f(x)\\
\end{align}

so
\begin{align}
f(x) &= \frac{2\sin(x+4)+(x+1)^2-(x+3)^2+(x+5)^2-(x+7)^2}{2}\\
&= \sin(x+4)-4x-16
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2):

Let's do two change of variables. First, $u = x-1$:

$$f(u+2) = (u+1)^2 - f(u)$$

Let's apply that multiple times:

$$\begin{align}
f(u+4) &= (u+3)^2 - f(u+2) = (u+3)^2 - (u+1)^2 + f(u)\\
f(u+6) &= (u+5)^2 - f(u+4) = (u+5)^2 - (u+3)^2 + (u+1)^2 - f(u)\\
f(u+8) &= (u+7)^2 - f(u+6) = (u+7)^2 - (u+5)^2 + (u+3)^2 - (u+1)^2 + f(u)
\end{align}$$

Which can be simplified to:

$$f(u+8) = 8u + 32 + f(u)$$

However we can also do the variable substitution $u = x - 4$ in our second identity:

$$f(u+8) = 2\sin (u+4) - f(u)$$

Giving equation:

$$8x + 32 + f(x) = 2\sin (x+4) - f(x)$$
$$2f(x) = 2\sin (x+4) - 8x - 32$$
$$f(x) = \sin (x+4) - 4x - 16$$

Comment: Thank you so much!